# Additional information: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, rss

This is my code:

```
public async void getRss(string link) {

    lNews.Clear();
    lNewsTemp.Clear();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var rssContent = await client.GetStringAsync(link);

    var rssData = from rss in XElement.Parse(rssContent).Descendants("item")
                  select new
                  {
                      Title = rss.Element("title").Value,
                      Description = rss.Element("description").Value,
                      Link = rss.Element("link").Value,
                      PubDate = rss.Element("pubDate").Value
                  };

    foreach (var rss in rssData)
    {
        lNews.Add(new News
        {
            Title = rss.Title,
            Description = rss.Description,
            Link = rss.Link,
            PubDate = rss.PubDate
        });

        lNewsTemp.Add(new News
        {
            Title = rss.Title,
            Description = rss.Description,
            Link = rss.Link,
            PubDate = rss.PubDate
        });
    } 

}
```

if the link = link_1 = http://vnexpress.net/rss/tin-moi-nhat.rss, code run is good, but the link = link_2 = http://www.thanhnien.com.vn/rss/home.rss, when run, I have error:

An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

And rssContent have value (when I debug):

`"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0�\a\u001cI�%&/m�{\u007fJ�J��t�\b�\u0013$ؐ@\u0..."`

But, link = link_2 run is good in another network.

Can you explain for me, and help me to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: I've no idea what rssContent is, but it looks nothing like XML.

Comment: I thinks so, but why rssContent = "\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0�\a\u001cI�%&/m�{\u007fJ�J��t�\b�\u0013$ؐ@\u0...". It's load content of website?

Comment: How should I know what the website contains?

Comment: The website is Rss feed. I want to get news by use Rss feed.

Comment: Well the stuff you're reading definitely isn't RSS. Perhaps "link" contains the wrong URL.

Comment: But, I use the internet in somewhere, the link_2 run OK.

Comment: This conversation is going nowhere. There is no way anyone can help you, from the information provided, to know why this particular variable has this particular content.